# addEventListener and display uncaught errors

Tags: javascript, html, css, typescript

So i have a code from my website:

```
<ul class="list-group col-6">
                <li class="list-item"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i><span class="span-social">Twitter</span></a></li>
                <li class="list-item"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-instagram"></i><span class="span-social">Twitter</span></a></li>
                <li class="list-item"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i><span class="span-social">Twitter</span></a></li>
                <li class="list-item"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-github"></i><span class="span-social">Twitter</span></a></li>
            </ul>
```

JS:

```
function showSocial() {
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("span-social");
  if (x.style.display === "none") {
    x.className = "show";
  } else {
    x.className = "span-social";
  }
}
var x = document.getElementsByClassName("list-group").children;
x.addEventListener("mouseover", showSocial());
```

CSS:

```
ul a {
  display: block;
  padding: 1em 1em;
  background-color: #fca311;
  color: white;
}

ul a .span-social {
  display: none;
  opacity: 0;
  margin-left: 5px;
  font-size: 14px;
  -webkit-transition: display .5s linear, opacity .33s linear;
  transition: display .5s linear, opacity .33s linear;
}

ul a .show {
  display: inline-block;
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0s;
          transition-delay: 0s;
}
```

But it seems that the js doesn't work , i tried with jquery hide and show events but i want to change the class especially because i have an animation here

Comment: `getElementsByClassName` returns a collection, not an element. You'll have to iterate over the collections. Also `.addEventListener("mouseover", showSocial());` will invoke the function immediately - you want to just *pass* the function to `addEventListener`

Comment: I tried something , i don't get errors but it seems to not work

 function showSocial() {
    var li = document.getElementsByClassName('span-social');
    for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
        var showli = li[i];

        if (showli.style.display === "none") {
            showli.classList.add("span-social show");
        } else {
            showli.className = "span-social";
        }
    }
}
var x = document.getElementsByClassName('list-item');
for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].addEventListener('mouseover', showSocial())
}

Comment: See the last part of my comment: *.addEventListener("mouseover", showSocial()); will invoke the function immediately - you want to just pass the function to addEventListener*